# OsmBonusPack ofline POI search from Mapsforge map file

Tags: android, osmdroid, mapsforge

Please bare with the newbie..

Having gone through a few posts here, it seems to be possible a holy grail with Mapsforge, osmdroid, graphhopper and OsmBonusPack for offline routing and turn by turn navigation.

I want to develop an android app for my City, completely offline. Is it possible to have "Offline" version of OSMNavigator, in the sense that it will have POI search from a local city.map file, feature list with distances from MyLocation etc. (Like OSMAnd in offline mode). Any help is most needed.

Thanks & Regards. .

Answer (score 3):

(As you know, the holy grail is always searched, and never reached...)

POI search from a local city.map file is not implemented in OSMBonusPack.

About Mapsforge/osmdroid integration: yes, it works. But it's experimental, and not really maintained. I'm not sure you should base a professional application on that.

Why not use the native MapsForge, with Graphhopper offline?

For POI, I'm not MapsForge expert, but apparently there is:

- a [mapsforge-poi-reader](https://code.google.com/r/neumann89-mapsforge-poi-searching) project related to Offline POI search
- and some work in progress inside MapsForge: https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/issues/728